# Load an external html file into webview

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm having problems loading an external html file into the webview.  I've done this before and it should be easy, but for some reason I keep getting Web page not available.

I know the files are in the directory because I placed them myself using file explorer.

```
String filename = "file:///"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Android/data/com.example/files/test_html2.html";
webview.loadUrl(filename);
```

I've tried moving the files into root and trying there, I've removed file:// and replaced it with content:// and nothing at all.  I have read permissions in the manifest.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't create `file://` URLs yourself, as you will tend to screw them up. In this case, I think that you have four slashes after the `:`, three that you typed in and one from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

Instead, create a `File` object and use that as the basis:

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Android/data/com.example/files/test_html2.html");
webview.loadUrl(f.toURI().toURL());   // or use Uri.fromFile(f).toString() instead
```

Comment: Thanks, been scratching my head over this for ages!